# Zip using "wp-scripts plugin-zip" with custom "build" folder and subfolders?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

I rename the default `build` folder to `blocks`, but when I execute the command for zip `npm run plugin-zip` I get only two files in the zip output (dts-haya.php, readme.txt).

My folder blocks contain two custom blocks, and the src folder two blocks. When I return with the default build folder and execute the zip command the plugin is zip correctly with the build folder and her subfolders (dyslocosaurus, miragaia).

How I set `npm run plugin-zip` locate the custom folder `blocks`?

```
my-plugin/
├─ node_modules/
├─ blocks/
│  ├─ dyslocosaurus/
│  ├─ miragaia/
├─ src/
│  ├─ dyslocosaurus/
│  ├─ miragaia/
├─ README.txt
├─ dts-haya.php
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "dts-haya",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Blocks for DetonaSaurus.",
    "author": "DetonaSaurus",
    "license": "-",
    "homepage": "-",
    "main": "blocks/",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "wp-scripts build --output-path=blocks",
        "format": "wp-scripts format",
        "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
        "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
        "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update",
        "plugin-zip": "wp-scripts plugin-zip",
        "start": "wp-scripts start --output-path=blocks"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wordpress/scripts": "^26.14.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: The documentation has this: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-scripts/#advanced-information-8 Does that help?

Comment: I tried, it's work, but now the package.json goes to the zip file too.